Why SVG is clipping after merging paths?
I have an SVG given below. I have merged all paths into one. But my final SVG is clipping. Can anyone help? Before and after screenshots are attached:
Before:
<svg width="21" height="22" viewBox="0 0 21 22" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M18.5952 17.7136L16.8883 14.2878C16.7414 14.0032 16.4482 13.8138 16.1284 13.8138H12.968V10.7403C12.968 10.2664 12.5815 9.8739 12.1149 9.8739C11.6482 9.8739 11.2617 10.2664 11.2617 10.7403V14.6808C11.2617 15.1548 11.6482 15.5472 12.1149 15.5472H15.6081L17.0748 18.4992C17.2217 18.797 17.5279 18.9731 17.8347 18.9731C17.968 18.9731 18.1014 18.9461 18.2211 18.8784C18.6347 18.6615 18.8082 18.1468 18.5952 17.7136Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M14.3166 17.0235C13.7301 17.5381 12.9832 17.8359 12.2098 17.8359C10.4499 17.8359 9.03624 16.3872 9.03624 14.6132C9.03624 13.6114 9.48937 12.6767 10.2764 12.0543C10.6498 11.7565 10.7165 11.2149 10.4232 10.8356C10.13 10.4564 9.59668 10.3887 9.22323 10.6865C8.00967 11.6343 7.31641 13.056 7.31641 14.5994C7.31641 17.3344 9.50284 19.5555 12.1967 19.5555C13.3832 19.5555 14.5165 19.1223 15.4233 18.3231C15.7832 18.0115 15.8098 17.4699 15.5035 17.1044C15.2098 16.7527 14.6635 16.7252 14.3166 17.0235Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M13.5587 7.91063C13.5587 8.7257 12.9077 9.38628 12.1053 9.38628C11.3027 9.38628 10.6523 8.72565 10.6523 7.91063C10.6523 7.09562 11.3028 6.43445 12.1053 6.43445C12.9078 6.43445 13.5587 7.0956 13.5587 7.91063Z" fill="black"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M7.34438 18.4364C7.34438 18.8637 6.99197 19.2103 6.55707 19.2103C6.12237 19.2103 5.76976 18.8639 5.76976 18.4364V13.1549C5.76976 13.0758 5.70415 13.0113 5.62374 13.0113H5.60087C5.52045 13.0113 5.45484 13.0758 5.45484 13.1549V18.4364C5.45484 18.8637 5.10242 19.2103 4.66753 19.2103C4.23263 19.2103 3.88022 18.8639 3.88022 18.4364C3.88022 15.0285 3.88022 11.3636 3.88022 7.93933C3.88022 7.86028 3.81461 7.79579 3.73419 7.79579H3.71132C3.63091 7.79579 3.5653 7.86028 3.5653 7.93933C3.5653 9.40132 3.5653 10.5185 3.5653 11.9805C3.5653 12.3153 3.28918 12.5868 2.94876 12.5868C2.60815 12.5868 2.33203 12.3153 2.33203 11.9805C2.33203 10.4045 2.33203 9.17356 2.33203 7.59752C2.33203 6.64743 3.12028 5.87258 4.08679 5.87258C5.10374 5.87258 6.12087 5.87258 7.13781 5.87258C8.10432 5.87258 8.89257 6.64743 8.89257 7.59752C8.89257 9.17356 8.89257 10.4045 8.89257 11.9805C8.89257 12.3153 8.61645 12.5868 8.27584 12.5868C7.93524 12.5868 7.65931 12.3153 7.65931 11.9805C7.65931 10.5185 7.65931 9.40132 7.65931 7.93933C7.65931 7.86028 7.5937 7.79579 7.51328 7.79579H7.49041C7.40999 7.79579 7.34438 7.86028 7.34438 7.93933C7.34438 11.3638 7.34438 15.0287 7.34438 18.4364ZM5.6123 2.44446C6.44704 2.44446 7.12394 3.10967 7.12394 3.9304C7.12394 4.75094 6.44722 5.41634 5.6123 5.41634C4.77738 5.41634 4.10067 4.75113 4.10067 3.9304C4.10067 3.10967 4.77757 2.44446 5.6123 2.44446Z" fill="black"/>
</svg>


After:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   x="0px" y="0px"
   width="24px"
   height="24px"
   viewBox="0 0 24 24"
   id="companion-24">
   
<!-- Merged all paths -->
<path fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M18.5952 17.7136L16.8883 14.2878C16.7414 14.0032 16.4482 13.8138 16.1284 13.8138H12.968V10.7403C12.968 10.2664 12.5815 9.8739 12.1149 9.8739C11.6482 9.8739 11.2617 10.2664 11.2617 10.7403V14.6808C11.2617 15.1548 11.6482 15.5472 12.1149 15.5472H15.6081L17.0748 18.4992C17.2217 18.797 17.5279 18.9731 17.8347 18.9731C17.968 18.9731 18.1014 18.9461 18.2211 18.8784C18.6347 18.6615 18.8082 18.1468 18.5952 17.7136ZM14.3166 17.0235C13.7301 17.5381 12.9832 17.8359 12.2098 17.8359C10.4499 17.8359 9.03624 16.3872 9.03624 14.6132C9.03624 13.6114 9.48937 12.6767 10.2764 12.0543C10.6498 11.7565 10.7165 11.2149 10.4232 10.8356C10.13 10.4564 9.59668 10.3887 9.22323 10.6865C8.00967 11.6343 7.31641 13.056 7.31641 14.5994C7.31641 17.3344 9.50284 19.5555 12.1967 19.5555C13.3832 19.5555 14.5165 19.1223 15.4233 18.3231C15.7832 18.0115 15.8098 17.4699 15.5035 17.1044C15.2098 16.7527 14.6635 16.7252 14.3166 17.0235ZM13.5587 7.91063C13.5587 8.7257 12.9077 9.38628 12.1053 9.38628C11.3027 9.38628 10.6523 8.72565 10.6523 7.91063C10.6523 7.09562 11.3028 6.43445 12.1053 6.43445C12.9078 6.43445 13.5587 7.0956 13.5587 7.91063ZM7.34438 18.4364C7.34438 18.8637 6.99197 19.2103 6.55707 19.2103C6.12237 19.2103 5.76976 18.8639 5.76976 18.4364V13.1549C5.76976 13.0758 5.70415 13.0113 5.62374 13.0113H5.60087C5.52045 13.0113 5.45484 13.0758 5.45484 13.1549V18.4364C5.45484 18.8637 5.10242 19.2103 4.66753 19.2103C4.23263 19.2103 3.88022 18.8639 3.88022 18.4364C3.88022 15.0285 3.88022 11.3636 3.88022 7.93933C3.88022 7.86028 3.81461 7.79579 3.73419 7.79579H3.71132C3.63091 7.79579 3.5653 7.86028 3.5653 7.93933C3.5653 9.40132 3.5653 10.5185 3.5653 11.9805C3.5653 12.3153 3.28918 12.5868 2.94876 12.5868C2.60815 12.5868 2.33203 12.3153 2.33203 11.9805C2.33203 10.4045 2.33203 9.17356 2.33203 7.59752C2.33203 6.64743 3.12028 5.87258 4.08679 5.87258C5.10374 5.87258 6.12087 5.87258 7.13781 5.87258C8.10432 5.87258 8.89257 6.64743 8.89257 7.59752C8.89257 9.17356 8.89257 10.4045 8.89257 11.9805C8.89257 12.3153 8.61645 12.5868 8.27584 12.5868C7.93524 12.5868 7.65931 12.3153 7.65931 11.9805C7.65931 10.5185 7.65931 9.40132 7.65931 7.93933C7.65931 7.86028 7.5937 7.79579 7.51328 7.79579H7.49041C7.40999 7.79579 7.34438 7.86028 7.34438 7.93933C7.34438 11.3638 7.34438 15.0287 7.34438 18.4364ZM5.6123 2.44446C6.44704 2.44446 7.12394 3.10967 7.12394 3.9304C7.12394 4.75094 6.44722 5.41634 5.6123 5.41634C4.77738 5.41634 4.10067 4.75113 4.10067 3.9304C4.10067 3.10967 4.77757 2.44446 5.6123 2.44446Z"/>
</svg>




In order to solve the problem you will need to reverse the second path, the one drawing the wheelchair. Otherwise the overlapping part of the path will be empty. Please read more about fill-rule in SVG


<svg width="210" height="220" viewBox="0 0 21 22" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M18.5952 17.7136L16.8883 14.2878C16.7414 14.0032 16.4482 13.8138 16.1284 13.8138H12.968V10.7403C12.968 10.2664 12.5815 9.8739 12.1149 9.8739C11.6482 9.8739 11.2617 10.2664 11.2617 10.7403V14.6808C11.2617 15.1548 11.6482 15.5472 12.1149 15.5472H15.6081L17.0748 18.4992C17.2217 18.797 17.5279 18.9731 17.8347 18.9731C17.968 18.9731 18.1014 18.9461 18.2211 18.8784C18.6347 18.6615 18.8082 18.1468 18.5952 17.7136Z
         M14.3166,17.0235L14.3166,17.0235C14.6635,16.7252 15.2098,16.7527 15.5035,17.1044C15.8098,17.4699 15.7832,18.0115 15.4233,18.3231C14.5165,19.1223 13.3832,19.5555 12.1967,19.5555C9.50284,19.5555 7.31641,17.3344 7.31641,14.5994C7.31641,13.056 8.00967,11.6343 9.22323,10.6865C9.59668,10.3887 10.13,10.4564 10.4232,10.8356C10.7165,11.2149 10.6498,11.7565 10.2764,12.0543C9.48937,12.6767 9.03624,13.6114 9.03624,14.6132C9.03624,16.3872 10.4499,17.8359 12.2098,17.8359C12.9832,17.8359 13.7301,17.5381 14.3166,17.0235Z
         M13.5587 7.91063C13.5587 8.7257 12.9077 9.38628 12.1053 9.38628C11.3027 9.38628 10.6523 8.72565 10.6523 7.91063C10.6523 7.09562 11.3028 6.43445 12.1053 6.43445C12.9078 6.43445 13.5587 7.0956 13.5587 7.91063Z 
         M7.34438 18.4364C7.34438 18.8637 6.99197 19.2103 6.55707 19.2103C6.12237 19.2103 5.76976 18.8639 5.76976 18.4364V13.1549C5.76976 13.0758 5.70415 13.0113 5.62374 13.0113H5.60087C5.52045 13.0113 5.45484 13.0758 5.45484 13.1549V18.4364C5.45484 18.8637 5.10242 19.2103 4.66753 19.2103C4.23263 19.2103 3.88022 18.8639 3.88022 18.4364C3.88022 15.0285 3.88022 11.3636 3.88022 7.93933C3.88022 7.86028 3.81461 7.79579 3.73419 7.79579H3.71132C3.63091 7.79579 3.5653 7.86028 3.5653 7.93933C3.5653 9.40132 3.5653 10.5185 3.5653 11.9805C3.5653 12.3153 3.28918 12.5868 2.94876 12.5868C2.60815 12.5868 2.33203 12.3153 2.33203 11.9805C2.33203 10.4045 2.33203 9.17356 2.33203 7.59752C2.33203 6.64743 3.12028 5.87258 4.08679 5.87258C5.10374 5.87258 6.12087 5.87258 7.13781 5.87258C8.10432 5.87258 8.89257 6.64743 8.89257 7.59752C8.89257 9.17356 8.89257 10.4045 8.89257 11.9805C8.89257 12.3153 8.61645 12.5868 8.27584 12.5868C7.93524 12.5868 7.65931 12.3153 7.65931 11.9805C7.65931 10.5185 7.65931 9.40132 7.65931 7.93933C7.65931 7.86028 7.5937 7.79579 7.51328 7.79579H7.49041C7.40999 7.79579 7.34438 7.86028 7.34438 7.93933C7.34438 11.3638 7.34438 15.0287 7.34438 18.4364ZM5.6123 2.44446C6.44704 2.44446 7.12394 3.10967 7.12394 3.9304C7.12394 4.75094 6.44722 5.41634 5.6123 5.41634C4.77738 5.41634 4.10067 4.75113 4.10067 3.9304C4.10067 3.10967 4.77757 2.44446 5.6123 2.44446Z" />
</svg>




Thanks a ton, Please help , how did you reverse second path. Is there any utility function for this

Can i use this library for path reversal https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-path-reverse  ?

I'm using this: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/RONoRN/8035d46f85b1cbdb8bcd1acd2850bc83 but you can try to use the one mentioned above
